# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php

I am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/core/functions/users.php on line 8

The piece of code that im getting an error is:

```
function recover($mode, $email) {
    $mode   = sanitize($mode);
    $email  = sanitize($email);

    $user_data = user_data(user_id_from_email($email), 'first_name', 'username');

    if ($mode == 'username') {
        email($email, 'Your username', 'Hello " . $user_data['first_name'] . ", \n\n Your username is: " . $user_data['username'] . " ');
    } elseif ($mode == 'password') {
        $generated_password = substr(md5(rand(999, 999999)), 0, 8);
        die($generated_password);
    }

}
```

How can i fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably the confusion of `'` and `"` in your `email()` line (the `'Hello "` block of text

Comment: yeah! thanks! that was the problem :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You syntax is incorrect for the following line:

```
email($email, 'Your username', 'Hello " . $user_data['first_name'] . ", \n\n Your username is: " . $user_data['username'] . " ');
```

You can replace it with:

```
email($email, 'Your username', "Hello " . $user_data['first_name'] . ", \n\n Your username is: " . $user_data['username'] . " ");
```

But a much cleaner approach is to embed variables in your string:

```
email($email, 'Your username', "Hello {$user_data['first_name']}, \n\n Your username is: {$user_data['username']} ");
```